# How to add a script in wordpress theme footer dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to create a wordpress plugin to add below script in all pages. So I need to add that script in theme footer. How can I add it in footer.php using plugin?

eg script =

script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js">

also I wish to add it in before body closing tag..

Thank you..

Comment: is it a js file or php?

Comment: in which folder is your script?

Comment: script from other website..

Comment: OK, do you have the entire path in your source="xxx" attribute?

Comment: please paste your actual code here, so we can see what the problem is, because we've given you the right answers and this is a simple process, but I think you're dealing with an error if you don't already have it working by now

Comment: $option_name ='insert_footer';
$new_value = '<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>';
$deprecated = null;
$autoload = 'yes';

add_option( $option_name, $new_value, $deprecated, $autoload );

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load the script in your themes `functions.php` file. Else, directly embed the script in your themes `footer.php` file.

Comment: sorry, this answer is probably correct, I've been coding like a proper programmer in wordpress, not adapting to the framework.
though wp_enqueue_script works for jscript libraries that come installed with wordpress, or does it include other files you coded yourself? the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Thanks... i wish to add my own js file

Comment: $option_name ='insert_footer';
$new_value = '<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>';
$deprecated = null;
$autoload = 'yes';

add_option( $option_name, $new_value, $deprecated, $autoload );

Answer (score 0):

for a javascript script you can just open the footer.php file and add the reference in there before the closing body tag, or use an include if it's a php script;

```
...
   <script type="text/JavaScript" src="yourscript.js" />
   <?php
      include("yourscript.php");
   ?>
</body>
...
```

PS: make sure that your `.js` file is in the same directory as your footer.php